# how to process generic list List<MyClass> in java to fetch resultset in particular manner

Tags: java, mysql, generics

I am into making database driven FAQs for a company
i have a class Faq.java with variables

1.faqUid
2.faqQuestion
3.faqAnswer
4.companyUserRole

so i am fetching results from databse through dao as you all know.ie i have made a list<> datatype

```
private List<Faq> fetchFaqs;
fetchFaqs = faqService.fetchRnrFaq(rnrUser);
```

now fetchFaqs is a generic list having datatype as specified in faq.java.

Now lets say i am getting data like from the database

Skeleton :

faqUid   |   faqQuestion   |    faqAnswer   |   companyUserRole

Data :

1 | question1 | question2 | Super Admin
2 | question1 | question2 | Group Admin
3 | question1 | question2 | User

So as you can see i have same question and answer for all of three types of roles i.e Super Admin, Group Admin and User.

When i fetch normally i get

FREQUNTLY ASKED QUESTIONS

Q.1 Question 1
A.1 Answer 1

Q.2 Question 2
A.2 Answer 2

Q.3 Question 3
A.3 Answer 3

What i want to fetch is

FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTION (Super Admin)

Q.1 Question 1
A.1 Answer 1

FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTION (Group Admin)

Q.1 Question 1
A.1 Answer 1

FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTION (User)

Q.1 Question 1
A.1 Answer 1

How can i implement this?????????????.

PS. Nothing is hardcoded, everything is database driven

faq.java class

```
private String faqQuestion;
private String faqAnswer;
private String faqUid;
private String userRoleName;
```

and there respective getters and setters

Comment: I didn't even see any question mark.

Comment: @smutje question mark edited !!

Answer (score 0):

Group your result according to the `companyUserRole` field (in a `Map` for example) and process the results for every type.

Comment: @Zafta just fix the query to bring the data sorted by role, then group the data in application by using a `Map<String, List<Faq>>` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Faq class contains all the fields from you database, and that you can modify the query. IMHO the simplest way to get what you need is to sort you query with a `ORDER BY companyUserRole`. Then you can process like that (pseudo-code) :

```
currentRole = "";

for(Faq faq: fetchFaqs) {
    if ! currentRole.equals(faq.role) {
        currentRole = faq.role
        display_new_role_group_header()
    display_faq(faq)
```

That way :

- you correctly display a header on top of each group
- you questions/answers are displayed grouped by role
- you send only one query to your database
- the list of roles is database driven